# Adding a UIView xib to a UITableViewCell is not sizing correctly?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a UIView xib to add to a custom UITableViewCell. When I add the xib it is not sized correctly. I am adding it in a way so that there is a margin/padding on the top and bottom of the cell.

Like this:

```
00000000000000000000

00000
    0
    0
    0
00000

00000000000000000000
```

As you an see there is padding above and below the view, but it's x value is 0.

When I add the view to the table view cell it is not maintaining the correct size. Its width is correct, but its height always extends from the top of the table view cell to the bottom. It won't fit inside with the margins based around the size of view that I created. I can add the view programmatically fine with the same proportions, but I want to configure this using an xib. Is there a reason why the view is not being added correctly to this uitableviewcell and the height is not maintaining?

Comment: are you adding it to the cell or to the cell's .contentView?

Comment: I'm adding it to the cells contentView

Comment: Hm and why would you insist on using an XIB?

Comment: Because setting up the labels, views, etc. within that view I'm adding are easier to get in the exact right place by setting it up via xib.

Comment: You may want to check out storyboards

Comment: I'm using storyboards for my entire project. I need to create a custom view to add to this table view cell. You can't create custom UIView's in storyboards.

Comment: Yes, you can create custom views in a storyboard. Add whatever views you want to a cell, and set their constraints to give you the padding you want. Create a custom class (if you need one) and change the cells' class to that. Make any IBOutlets you need from the views to the custom class.

Comment: But that would require me adding the view to a UIViewController on the storyboard. You can't create stand alone UIViews.

Comment: Why do you want a stand alone view? Are you doing something else with this view, other than adding it to the cell? The easiest way to do this, is to make everything in the storyboard. If you must use a xib, after you add it to the cell's contentView, add constraints to it in code that will confine it to the correct size (probably constraints to all side of the cell, or to other UI elements you already have in the cell).